# If $K $ is infinite and $u,v $ are separable and algebraic over $K $ then there is some $a \in K $ such that $K (u+av)=K (u,v) $ proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, separable-extension

> Let $K $ be a field with infinite elements. Prove that if $u,v $ are separable and algebraic over $K $ then there is some $a \in K $ such that $K (u+av)=K (u,v) $. Is the result still true if $K$ is finite?

This question is from Kaplansky's [fields and rings](https://books.google.com/books?id=_KHjPspACS4C&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=show+if+K+is+not+finite+and+u+and+v+are+algebraic+and+separable+them+K+(u,v)%3DK+(u%2Bav)&source=bl&ots=ZUBqBfQT_g&sig=3Y1LiSsGSp48V3Yvo5eaUno4FHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp-fen1ZLbAhXohFQKHd3JA3QQ6AEwB3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=show%20if%20K%20is%20not%20finite%20and%20u%20and%20v%20are%20algebraic%20and%20separable%20them%20K%20(u%2Cv)%3DK%20(u%2Bav)&f=false) page 49.

Here is my proof for the first part:

As $K (u,v) $ is a simple extension of $K (u) $ which is in turn a simple extension of $K$, by the theorem on page 48 of the same book there is only a finite number of intermediate fields for $K (u,v)/K $. Considering the finite set $\{ K (u+av) : a \in K \} $, since $K $ is infinite there is some $K (u+av)=K (u+bv)$, and doing a similar process on page 48 proof we eventually get that $K (u,v) = K (u+av) $.

Here is my question: how does the fact that $u,v $ are separable are used? Is my proof correct or is it missing something?

Another update: it seems like, upon reflection, that the problem with my above 'proof' is that I am fixing a particular intermediate field $K(u)$. So, while for my particular field there may be only finite number of intermediate fields that 'fill the gap' between $K(u,v)$ and $K(u)$ and likewise 'fill the gap' between $K(u)$ and $K$ there may be infinite number of ways to choose an intermediate field. Is there a way to 'upgrade' my false proof in such a way that would solve the problem, and if not how should I approach this problem?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ have inseparable minimal polynomials [there may be infinitely many intermediate fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823100/11619).

Comment: But is this not a standard result? Proving the [existence of a primitive element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/745197/11619)